# Extend type to add rest parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a type

```
export type baseEventType = {
    eName: string;
    mName: string;
    
};
```

and I would like to extend it to take a rest parameter

```
interface gEvent extends baseEventType {
    ...rest: any[]
}
```

which obviously won't work

I would like to use it in this way

```
export const save = ({ eName, mName, ...rest }: gEvent) =>
```

So is there a way to make that work. Obviously the following would work

```
export const save = (eName: string, mName: string, ...rest: any[]) => {
```

but I would prefer if I can do something similar to the other structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca add an index signature to the `gEvent`, but this will in effect disable type checking for the argument, letting you pass in even properties in `baseEvetType` with any type:

```
export type baseEventType = {
    eName: string;
    mName: string;
};
interface gEvent extends baseEventType {
    [name: string]: any;
}

export const save = ({ eName, mName, ...rest }: gEvent) => {

}

save({
  eName: 0 // eName is declared as string but we can pass number because of the index signature
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBGBDAzsAogN2ADsYAVZVAXjgG8BYAKDmbmADkMBbYALjixhQAlkQDmAbkYs4nDtz4DhYyQwC+KkTGBQAZhgDGqUQWLxQWogBMs6bHkIlyKWlJYBtIl179BI0QF0+DCJEFVVGRlBIWDh9CCIBfgxCOGoAChpWOWAAGhlsvIA6YqhgRNU+YwcYAEpUgD4XBkZw5oYsZOAM13YvPgAGFpqgA)

Using an intesection type is probably a better idea here. This will do better when type checking the named properties:

```
type gEvent = baseEventType & {
    [name: string]: any;
}

export const save = ({ eName, mName, ...rest }: gEvent) => {

}

save({
  eName: 0, // error
  other: "", // ok
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBGBDAzsAogN2ADsYAVZVAXjgG8BYAKDmbmADkMBbYALjixhQAlkQDmAbkYs4nDtz4DhYyQwC+KpCjiiCxeNUw5dJcloBktKSwDaRLr36CRogLp8MRRCtWNGoSLBwAMYQRAL8GIRw1AAUNKxywAA0MokpAHSZUMDhqnw6hCQAlNEAfJYMjD6VDFiRwHFW7PZ8AAwpAPQdrFBQ0FYQMAAWwFB8AETjVUVAA)